# How can I use a custom executor for an @Async method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, threadpoolexecutor

I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` as my custom executor with `@ASync` annotation.

In google, I have found that the task below needs to be configured in `xml` but I'm not sure how the `myExecutor` is mapped to my custom executor.

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />
```

Even found that in bean properties, its path is not given.

How is it called then?

Answer (score 1):

Four options:

1. Declare a single bean of type `TaskExecutor`
2. Declare a single bean with the name `AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME` (`"taskExecutor"`)
3. Implement [`AsyncConfigurer#getAsyncExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html)
4. For individual classes/methods, provide a qualifier of an executor bean in the [`@Async#value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html#value--).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but your configuration snippet is correct provided that you have defined an `Executor` bean with `myExecutor` as id.

The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) of `@EnableAsync` has a good coverage of how this works. For instance, to create a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with 5 core threads and 10 max threads:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5-10"/>
```